# Does tx run in the order of being included in the block?

Tags: transactions, consensus, nonce

When the block is executed,

Should the order of txs included in the block be the same as the order of the nonce? Or can it be different?
For example, when trying to run three txs (nonce is 1, 2, 3) from A(EOA) in the same block, should the nonce order of txs be 1, 2, 3? or can it run even if it is 1, 3, 2?

Answer (score 0):

The transactions of the same EOA will always execute in the order of the nonce. This is necessary to ensure that the account can pay the required fees before processing a tx.

Comment: I was wondering what if the order of txs in the block is not same as the order of nonces. Can txs still be succeeded?

Comment: That cannot happen, as the consensus protocol defines that this is the order.

Comment: TX Execution on page 8 of the yellow paper